# Batch-file to remove part of a number before passing it to an application

Tags: batch-file

I've been racking my brain trying to get my softphone to dial numbers on web pages. I've gotten the browser to pass the number through to the softphone, but it adds tell:+ to the number and won't call out.

As a matter of last resort, I want to create a batch file to remove the tel:+ from the number. I have never written one before, but I imagine that it would be relatively simple.

The batch file just needs to open the tel: urls and remove tell:+ from the number before passing it on to the softphone.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "URI=%~1"
set "URI=%URI:tel:+=%"
somecommand %URI%
```

Pass the URI as argument.

See `help set` for a detailed description.

Comment: The argument might possibly need to be stripped off the quotation marks first, for safety.

Comment: I think I understand most of that. Definitely gives me an idea of where to get started. I'm going to read a few tutorials and poke around.